# How Do I Make This Code Set the Value of the Instance Variable?

Tags: ruby, class, dynamic, methods, instance-variables

I have the following code, meant to turn a normal variable into an instance variable.

```
BasicObject.class_eval do
    def instance(ins)
        self.instance_variable_set("@#{ins}", ins)
    end
end
```

Lets say the user says

```
class X
  foo = 3
end
bar = X.new
bar.instance(:foo)
```

What I want it to do is set the new created variable, `@foo` to 3, instead, it sets `@foo` to `:foo`. How do I make the code do what I want?

Comment: The code example defines a `foo` that is only visible within that `class` ... `end` block.  Even if you go back into class X, it's gone - it's part of the lexical scope, not the class. Those 'normal' variables are never visible outside the scope in which they're created.  Once you hit the `end` that closes their block, they can only be accessed by code defined within that block.  And there isn't any such code above.
What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Why on earth do you want this convoluted code, anyhow? What is your goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `instance` method, the parameter `ins` contains the name of the variable, not its value.  As written, there's no way to get at its value from that point.

If you call `instance` from a point in the code where the source variable is actually visible, which it's not in your example (see my comment above), you can also pass the local variable binding, and then use that.  Something like this:

```
def instance(var, bound)
    eval "@#{var}=#{var}", bound
end
```

Which would work like this:

```
foo = 3
instance('foo', binding)
@foo   # => 3
```

Comment: im confused, whaddaya mean by binding?

Comment: A Binding object, which represents the set of variables visible at a certain point in the code.  The current binding is returned by the `binding` method, so the above code is literal; `binding` is predeclared, and you don't have to do anything to make it work.  You can take the result and pass it as the second argument to `eval`, which makes the same set of variables visible to the `eval`ed code - that's pretty much all you can do with a Binding object.

Comment: See [`Binding`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Binding.html) and [`Kernel#binding`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-binding).